# Converting a row in a column to LocalDate in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm having a problem when I try to filter `data` where `data < todayData`

If I use this code, I get the wrong results
Code:

```
val todayData = LocalDate.now.format(
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")) //22/09/2021


val filtredDF = sampleData.where(sampleData("data_riferimento_condizioni") < todayData)
```

One of reuslt:

```
+--------+--------+---------------------------+-----------+
|istituto|servizio|data_riferimento_condizioni|      stato|
+--------+--------+---------------------------+-----------+
|   62952|     923|                 02/12/2022|in progress|
+--------+--------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

As you can see I get data that > todayDate, I want to bring data_riferimento_condizioni to LocalDate so I can use [public boolean isBefore(ChronoLocalDate other)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)

Comment: What datatype is "data_riferimento_condizioni" in your dataframe?

Comment: "data_riferimento_condizioni" is String

Comment: Everything in this dataframe is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to convert "data_riferimento_condizioni" to DateType or TimestampType instead StringType with to_date() or to_timestamp() functions from [there](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) and then filter your data

For spark 3 and newer you can filter out you rows comparing them with instances of java.time.LocalDate or java.time.Instant

```scala
val filtredDF = sampleData
    .withColumn("converted", to_date(col("data_riferimento_condizioni"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
    .where(col("converted") < LocalDate.now)
```

But if you're using spark 2, you have to convert your LocalDate or Instant to java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp

```scala
val filtredDF = sampleData
    .withColumn("converted", to_date(col("data_riferimento_condizioni"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
    .where(col("converted") < Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now))
```

You can read more about using dates in spark and differences between spark2 and spark3 [there](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html)

Comment: Unsupported literal type class java.time.LocalDate 2021-09-23

Comment: I'm sorry, I added example for spark3. Based on your exception i assumed you're using spark 2 so I updated my answer